# Filter MDX measure by dimension members

Tags: mdx

Let's say I have a dimension of customers, and I'd like to get all those customers, who generated revenue greater than 100... How do you do that in MDX? I have created a member, using a filter such as this

```
Filter([Dim Customer].[Id].Members, [Measures].[Revenue] > 150)
```

However it's not working as expected. How do you usually go around this? I'd like to see 1 row, with 2 columns, all revenue and the revenue from customers that generated more than 150. My problem is that since I don't want the rows of customer to be displayed on the rows axis - it is not considering the filter per customer, but on the whole [Measures].[Revenue].

Answer (score 1):

Remember that the Filter()-function returns a set, namely the set of all customers with a revenue over 150. You then need to specify that you want to aggregate something over this set. This means your calculated measure should like this:

```
WITH MEMBER [Measures].[Revenue for Customers over 150] AS
    Aggregate(
        Filter(Existing ([Dim Customer].[Id].Members),
            [Measures].[Revenue] > 150),
        [Measures].[Revenue]
    )
```

Comment: Thanks @Dan. When I did this, and created my MDX query to show this column, against the total of [Measures].[Revenue], I see [Measures].[Revenue] less than the Revenue for customers over 150. This is impossible because [Measures].[Revenue for Customers over 150] is a subset of    [Measures].[Revenue]. Any ideas?

Comment: Do you have any customers with negative revenue?

Comment: That sounds very strange. What do you get if you execute the following MDX statement directly: `WITH MEMBER [Measures].[Revenue for Customers over 150] AS Aggregate(Filter([Dim Customer].[Id].Members, [Measures].[Revenue] > 150), [Measures].[Revenue]) SELECT {[Measures].[Revenue],[Measures].[Revenue for Customers over 150]} ON 0 FROM [MyCube]`

Comment: If I execute that directly, it shows me the total amount which is far greater. I thought that the member is for some strange reason not considering the filtering clauses in the WHERE however it is not the case.

Comment: Are you filtering away some of the customers in the WHERE-clause? That explains it then, since the FILTER()-function does not take the current context into account, but evaluates the set in the context of the entire cube. To get around this, add `EXISTING` to your calculated measure - I've edited my post to show how.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/54437/discussion-between-mez-and-dan).

Answer (score 0):

the filter() function should do:

```
SELECT [Measures].[Internet Sales Amount] ON 0,
filter(
[Customer].[Customer].[Customer].MEMBERS
, [Measures].[Internet Sales Amount] > 150
) ON 1 
FROM [Adventure Works]
```

About half of the customers are filtered out.

Philip,

Comment: Hi Philip, you are referring to a hierarchy, but in my case I don't have one. I have an attribute [Id], in the dimension for customers.